# какая последняя версия Node js еще будет работать на Windows XP

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте, ситуация такая, нужно мигрировать на какое-то время, а там только XP-шка какая последняя версия Node js еще будет работать на Windows XP? Спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С версии 6.0.0 не поддерживаются Windows XP и Windows Vista. Так что последняя версия для Windows XP это - 5.12.0